# Promises in Angular: infinite calls when returning directly

Tags: angular, typescript, es6-promise

I am more familiar with `Observables` than `Promises` so I was toying with a use of  promises, in my `.ts` file:

```
response = {};

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getCallback();
}

async getCallback() {
  console.log("getCallback: calling backend");
  this.response = await this.http.get(this.apiURL).toPromise();
  console.log("getCallback: got answer")
}

async getCallback2() {
    console.log("getCallback2: calling backend");
    const ret = await this.http.get(this.apiURL).toPromise();
    console.log("getCallback2: got answer");
    return ret;
}
```

and my `.html` file:

```
<pre> {{ response | json}} </pre>
<pre> {{ getCallback2() | json}} </pre>
```

This is two different ways of displaying the return from a (trivial) backend call. What I see is that the first way (using `this.response` to store the result) works properly: single call to backend and display of correct return. While `getCallback2()` calls infinitely the backend and does not display the expected return. Is it a conflict with the change detection on the `DOM` side? I cannot understand why I am observing two different behaviours..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you add an Angular expression in View like {{expression}}, it would be added to watch list of current scope.

Angular uses a mechanism called dirty checking to archive two way binding. Each time some specific events happen, Angular will go through the watch list to check whether the watched value has changed or not, this action is called as digest loop.

Here some specific events consist of user input, model change, http requests finish, etc. As you are using a function getLink in the expression, each time when Angular trigger a dirty check/digest loop, this function will be executed once again to check whether its return result has changed.

The problem is, the function getCallback2 here is a http request, after it's executed, Angular will triggered another round dirty check ,which will execute this function again ... Bang, it's an infinite loop.

Comment: Many thanks for the input. Angular's change detection is a complete black box to me =)